# How to remove first 4 bytes from s string in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I got a special packet in string format, which has 32 bytes header and the body contains one of more entries, each consist of 90 bytes.

I want to process this string using python. Can I just read like sock read first 32 bytes header,  and take it off the string, and continue read 90 bytes of the first entry?

something like:

```
str.read(32) # => "x01x02..."
str.read(90) # => "x02x05..."
```

Comment: slicing ( s[5:] ) doesn't help?

Comment: Are you using python 2.x or 3.x ?

Comment: @Roberto I'm using python 2.x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to read a string like a file

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> s = 'Hello, World!'
>>> sio = StringIO.StringIO(s)
>>> sio.read(6)
'Hello,'
>>> sio.read()
' World!'
```

I would also suggest you take a look at the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module for help with parsing binary data

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3)
'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03'
>>> unpack('hhl', '\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03')
(1, 2, 3)
```

You define the format of the data using format strings, so `'hhl'` in the above example is `short (2 bytes), short (2 bytes), int (4 bytes)`. It also supports specifying endianness (byte order) in the format string.

For example if your header format was `uint, 4 byte str, uint, uint, ushort, ulong`:

```
>>> import struct
>>> data = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(128)) * 10
>>> hdr_fmt = 'I4sIIHL'
>>> struct.calcsize(hdr_fmt)
32
>>> struct.unpack_from(hdr_fmt, data, 0)
(50462976, '\x04\x05\x06\x07', 185207048, 252579084, 4368, 2242261671028070680)
```

Answer (score 5):

To split the packet into a 32 byte header and body:

```
header = packet[:32]
body = packet[32:]
```

To further split the body into one or more entries:

```
entries = [packet[i:i+90] for i in range(0, len(packet), 90)]
```

Answer (score 4):

In python 2.x you could do simply:

```
header = s[:32]
body = s[32:32+90]
```

In python 3.x all strings are unicode, so I would convert to bytearray firstly:

```
s = bytearray(s)
header = s[:32]
body = s[32:32+90]
```